# Taylor-Russell tables for dichotomous criterion variables

Tags: proportion

Dear StackExchange visitors,

I am searching for syntax, preferably for Stata, SPSS or R, to be able to compute, so-called, *Taylor-Russell tables for dichotomous criterion variables* which lists the proportion of successful selectees for each combination of a point-biserial validity (*r*pb, or *r* tetrachoric correlation, also called the validity coefficient), a base rate, and a selection ratio.

Such tables were published by H.C. Taylor & J.T. Russell, The relationship of validity coefficients to the practical effectiveness of tests in selection, *Journal of Applied Psychology*,1939 (23) 5, 565-578, and by N.M. Abrahams, E.F. Alf & J.J. Wolfe, Taylor-Russell tables for dichotomous criterion variables, *Journal of Applied Psychology*, 1971 (55) 5, 449-457.

As an example, if the tetrachoric correlation is .55, the base rate is .5 and the selection ratio is .6, the proportion of successful selectees is .6976 (which can be found in the table published by Abrahams & Wolfe, 1971).

But, how can this proportion of successful selectees (.6976) be derived if only the tetrachoric correlation (.55), the base rate (.5) and the selection ratio (.6) are known?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any references that give the formulas or computational approaches used by either the 1939 or 1971 article?